# Error en una función de un componente

Tags: angular

aca les dejo mi codigo

Este es mi models

```
export interface Respuesta {
    num_reclamo: number;
    rut_admin: number;
    texto_respuesta: string;
    fecha_respuesta: string;
    SLA_respuesta: string;
}
```

Este es mi respuesta service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class RespuestaService {

       private URL = 'localhost:8080/api'
       httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
       };

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      responderReclamo(num_reclamo: number) {
          const suffix = '/ADMIN/pendientes/respuesta'
          return this.http.post(this.URL+suffix+num_reclamo, this.httpOptions);
        }
    }
```

Y este es mi componente.ts que es donde me marca el error

```
      import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
      import { Respuesta } from 'src/models/Respuesta';
      import { RespuestaService } from 'src/app/services/respuesta-service.service';
      import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
      import { Location } from '@angular/common';
      @Component({
         selector: 'app-respuesta-de-reclamo',
         templateUrl: './respuesta-de-reclamo.component.html',
         styleUrls: ['./respuesta-de-reclamo.component.css']
      })
      export class RespuestaDeReclamoComponent implements OnInit {

          @Input() respuesta: Respuesta;

          constructor(
            private respuestaService:RespuestaService,
            private ruta: ActivatedRoute,
            private ubicacion: Location
          ) {}

          ngOnInit(): void {}

          volver(){
             this.ubicacion.back();
          }

          guardar(num_reclamo:number, rut_admin:number, 
                  texto_respuesta:string, fecha_respuesta:string, 
                  SLA_respuesta: string){
              this.respuestaService
                  .responderReclamo({num_reclamo, 
                         rut_admin, texto_respuesta, fecha_respuesta, 
                         SLA_respuesta} as Respuesta)
                  .subscribe(_=>this.volver());
           }
      }
```

El error que me marca, al situarme encima de

> (property) Respuesta.texto_respuesta: string Argument of type
>   'Respuesta' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345

Agradezco sus respuestas!!

Comment: Hola. No entiendo donde te da el error.

Comment: Al situarme en la linea ({num_reclamo, rut_admin, texto_respuesta, fecha_respuesta, SLA_respuesta} as Respuesta), disculpa no me dejo subir mas codigo para señalar bien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La funcion `responderReclamo(num_reclamo: number)` recibe un parametro de tipo `number` y se llama `num_reclamo`. Si lo que quieres es recibir:

```
{num_reclamo, rut_admin, texto_respuesta, fecha_respuesta, SLA_respuesta} as Respuesta
```

Entonces modifica de esta manera:

```
responderReclamo(respuesta: Respuesta)
```

Y ya en tu servicio mandas :

```
const suffix = '/ADMIN/pendientes/respuesta'
    return this.http.post(this.URL+suffix+ this.respuesta.num_reclamo, this.httpOptions);
```

Comment: No me funciona, me marca error en responderReclamo esto.. : Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)
'Respuesta' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)  y tambien Cannot find name 'respuesta'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.respuesta'?ts(2663)   y en el service me lanza Cannot find name 'respuesta'.ts(2304)

Comment: Error mio. `Cannot find name 'respuesta'.` te da el error por que no puse el `this.respuesta`

Comment: Me pide declararla, la coloco como respuesta: any; o respuesta: Respuesta en el service

Comment: Checa mi pregunta. Edite el último bloque de comentario para que no te de el error.

Comment: Ya no me marco error, lo voy a probar

Comment: Funciono pero mal, o sea como que no me toma el suffix, porque en la consola me marco Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api3' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
:8080/api3:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
core.js:6210 ERROR HttpErrorResponse

Comment: Solucione, era que en el private url faltaba http://, ahora igual no me mostro el contenido del html, faltara algo que no deje mostrarlo?

Comment: No se a que parte te refieres.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107809/discussion-between-arthuro-ali-and-angel).